# Creating App on https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/

Tags: pinterest

I'm trying to create an App on https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/

The App state is still "in development" and the hint says I need at least 1 more collaborators allthough I already have three.

Furthermore, uploading an image as App Icon causes a JS error in the App Management Page ("Error" and http state 500)

How to get over that obstacles:
Define the app with all necessary settings like devs, testers and an Icon?

Comment: Axel, I have been searching Google for Pinterest API stuff and I keep seeing your posts, meaning how limited the docs are. I have created an app just like you did there. Can I start using it or how do I get rid of the in development message?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Actually, the "In Development" state is not for production, as the docs are claiming. You may use your app, but it might not give full functionality to your users, so better apply to their rules!